# Remove back to safari button in Swift iOS 9

Tags: swift2

When the swift app is open from the browser, the back to safari button in status bar is enabled. I don't want to see that button. How to hide the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an iOS 9 Feature that you cannot and should not hide.

Comment: hmmm thanks for your valuable reply ........ i also searched and got only as you said like that... can you able to confirm from apple website ?