# Swift + Parse: Facebook login flow has "Back to Safari" in iOS9

Tags: swift, facebook, parse-platform, swift2, facebook-login

Now, I know that the back button in the status bar is a new feature of iOS 9, but how do I prevent that from showing the "Back to Safari" on the left of the status bar once a user has logged in from facebook ?  I see other apps not having that issue, so how do I go about ensuring that that does not happen?

I can edit in any code or more information if needed.  I really want to figure this out.

Comment: The workaround is overlaying another view with same colour over a status bar. Please refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241412/add-uiview-banner-above-status-bar-ios-7
But I strongly encourage you not doing it.

Also a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964622/remove-back-to-safari-button-in-swift-ios-9

Comment: I haven't tested it, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247787/is-there-a-way-to-hide-back-to-safari-from-status-bar-in-ios9 has a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this reply is too long to put it in the comment textField:

I used this techniques in one of my apps.

In `AppDelegate` write this method for example:

```
    func buildUserInterface(){
    let objectID:String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("user_id")

    if objectID != nil {

        let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let singleMode:singleModeVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("singleModeVC") as! singleModeVC

        let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: singleMode)

        let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav
    }
}
```

It can therefore only be used, when you got a user logged in or just created.

In the `ViewController` handling the regristration/loggin in within the Login Block put this:

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

                    objectID = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(objectID, forKey: "user_id")




                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


                    // singleModeVC
                    let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let singleMode:singleModeVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("singleModeVC") as! singleModeVC

                    let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: singleMode)

                    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav
```

singleModeVC is the name and class of my view controller to appear after signing in. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll give this a try in a bit and let you know

Comment: I didn't use NSUserDefaults since I already have a PFUser and session tokens, but setting the window to the view controller I wanted after login authenticated got the behavior I wanted

Comment: Okay, its weird, it was working but now it stopped.  I didn't even change the code.

Comment: Can u try to log back in?

Comment: Hey, sorry I never selected this as the answer.  It has been awhile, so I do not remember exactly what I tweaked, but it WAS working.   So much of my code has changed since then, as has Swift, so I doubt this is relevant now.

Comment: @daredevil1234 it still works fine ! let me know if you still need help with this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. This is the default functionality in iOS 9. If you observe, the back button hides if you just go to background and come to foreground.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

Also you could try to initialize a real new `viewController` rather than performing a segue. I use it in some apps and it works fantastically .

Comment: It's the back button in the status bar, not the nav bar, that is causing me trouble

Comment: okay then try the 2nd attempt. Initialize a new view controller when you log in.

Comment: PS: Why down vote? It is possible, look up how you can initialize a new controller

Comment: I tried the initialize and it still did not remove the back button in the status bar

Comment: Please check my new answer, hope it helps.